# Lock-free slist erase

Tags: c++, algorithm, containers, atomic, lock-free

I have been trying to implement a lock-free slist erase operation but I'm having obiviously problems with it. Unfortunately I realy realy need it.

To solve usual ABA cmpxchg related problems I have written tagged_ptr<> "smart pointer" class that embeds a counter to the pointer stored in std::atomic<>. The tag value is incremented each time pointer is updated via CAS in the list:
`head.compare_exchange_weak(old, old(newptr))` stores `newptr` with incremented tag from `old`.
This allows multi-writer transactions, but it does not solve problems of updating two pointers simultaneously. (e.g implementing stack is easy with tagged_ptr<>)

See the code [here](https://gist.github.com/JATothrim/97aef4c46f5e4391eb07886732493078).
On line 256 is the erase() function:

```
bool erase(list_node * node) {
    std::atomic<tagged_ptr<list_node>>* before;
    tagged_ptr<list_node> itr, after;
    for(;;) {
        // Find previous (or head) before-node-ptr
        before = &head;
        itr = before->load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        while(itr) {
            if(itr.get() == node) {
                break;
            } else if(itr.is_void()) {
                // Thread interfered iteration.
                before = &head;
                itr = before->load(std::memory_order_acquire);
            } else {
                // Access next ptr
                before = &itr->next;
                itr = before->load(std::memory_order_acquire);
            }
        }

        after = node->next.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        if(after.is_void() || !itr) {
            return false;
        }

        // Point before-ptr to after. (set head or previous node's next ptr)
        if(before->compare_exchange_strong(itr, itr(after))) {
            // Set node->next to invalid ptr.
            // list iterators will see it and restart their operation.
            while(!node->next.compare_exchange_weak(after, after().set_void()))
                ;
            return true;
        }
        // If *before changed while trying to update it to after, retry search.
    }
}
```

In the test code two threads push nodes into list simultaneously and two threads search a random node by data and try erase them.
bug I'm having is:

- the list becomes cyclic (the list is null terminated) somehow and thus threads get stuck forever iterating the list never finding end of the list.

Comment: Not sure I understand the `tagged_ptr` code correctly. Let's say you are using a 32bit CPU, then `tag_type` is `uint32`, thus the `ptr` and `tag` overlap on the same position in memory (they are the same, since the padding is 0 byte).

Comment: If you are on a 64bits CPU, then `tag_type` is `uint16` and the low 16 bits of `ptr` gets are used to store the `tag`. (This seems wrong to me). As far as I remember, you should be safe with using the low 4 bits on a 32bit machine, and the high 16 bits on a 64bit machine (from 48 to 64 is not used)

Comment: Do you have some code to test your `tagged_ptr` implementation ?

Comment: Please check [this](https://nikic.github.io/2012/02/02/Pointer-magic-for-efficient-dynamic-value-representations.html)

Comment: I have tested the tagged_ptr<> class and it is functioning correctly. On x86_64 there is a trick that I can get away (on system that has 48-bit virtual address space) with cmpxchg8b instead of cmpxchg16b since upper 16-bits of addresses are not used. (this is bit flaky I know!)
I have successfully made a lock-free stack running on RPi2 with this class. If sizeof(void*) == 4 then sizeof(tagged_ptr<T>) == 8, if sizeof(void*) == 8 then sizeof(tagged_ptr<T>) == 8 and tag is stored in the unused high 16-bits of the address.

Comment: @xryl669 On 64-bit x86_64 machine the tag bits are stored in the 16 high bits of the ptr, defererencing tagged_ptr<> simply sets the tags bits to zero.

Comment: I'd recommend ditching your tagged_ptr class and moving toward the standard library functions for atomic shared_ptr. see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic they're replaced in c++20 with https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've some doubt concerning your `tagged_ptr` implementation. 
Also, I've some doubt concerning this part of the code:

```
         } else if(itr.is_void()) {
                // Thread interfered iteration.
                before = &head;
                itr = before->load(std::memory_order_acquire);
```

Let's say a thread removed the last node (you had 1 node in the list and both thread calls erase). The remaining thread will query the head pointer, it's void. You'll enter an infinite loop with this part of the code since it's in a `while(itr)` loop.

This part is also not atomic:

```
            // Point before-ptr to after. (set head or previous node's next ptr)
            if(before->compare_exchange_strong(itr, itr(after))) {
                // Set node->next to invalid ptr.
                // list iterators will see it and restart their operation.
                while(!node->next.compare_exchange_weak(after, after().set_void()))
                    ;
                return true;
}
```

If `before` is modified by the first CAS, your `node` is a unattached pointer still pointing to the list. Yet another thread can have its `before` set to this `node` and modify it and returns.
Honestly, if your list is cyclic, it's not that hard to debug, just break under a debugger and follow the list. You'll see when it loops and they you can figure out how it did it. You can also use valgrind for this.

The `tagged_ptr` class is hard to grasp, with the "set_void()" method that's setting the internal `ptr` to `0xFF..F` yet the boolean test in while(itr) will return true if it's "void". I guess the name should be **invalid** and not **void** and it should return false in the bool operator if it is (not true). If the itr becomes "void" (it's possible in the code above as far as I understand) the `while(itr)` will loop indefinitely.

For example, let say you had:

```
Head:A -> B -> C
```

Then after some thread removal you get

```
Thread 2 removing C : Head:A, before = &B on first iteration, exiting the while(itr) loop since itr == C (scheduled here)
Thread 1 removing B : Head:A->C and B->C (scheduled just before line 286 of your example)
Thread 2 resume, and will modify B to B->null (line 283)
and then C->null to C->yourVoid (line 286, then it's scheduled)

Then, thread 1 update B->next to B->yourVoid (useless here for understanding the issue)
You now have A->C->yourVoid
```

Whenever iterating here, you'll have an infinite loop since when itr search arrives on C, the next step is to be a "void" and restarting the iteration from head does not solve anything here, it'll give the same result, the list is broken.

Comment: Good point, however `while(itr)` *should* compare false in this case since head should never contain void ptr. (`head.load()` is either valid or null, never void)
Note that `before` ptr is either `&head` or `&node->next` in the code, thus if erase() removes the last node, cmpxchg will store null into `head` from `node->next`
The problem is that some error occurs and the list becomes *cyclic* with no nullptr terminating the list, and the threads get stuck in find().

Comment: Yup, I admit that naming of tagged_ptr<>::set_void() is bit confusing, it really means "invalid".
Thanks for analyzing the code and giving more structured view that I initially had. :)